# How to add a instant of fragment again?

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I have a problem with a fragment. I need to display a fragment many times and don't create new instant of it. I have a method that it use to change the content of activity.

```
protected void setContentFragment(Fragment contentFragment) {
    this.contentFragment = contentFragment;
    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment).commit();
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

content_frame is a simple layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The problem is: I create instant of the first Fragment and pass it to setContentFragment(...) (still keep instant of this). Then call setContentFragment with other Fragment. And now, I pass instant of the first Fragment to this method, it show bank screen. Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
    private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (getActivity() == null)
        return;

    if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
        DashboardActivity dashboard = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        dashboard.switchFragment(fragment, "Main List");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't try.because it's only a part of your code
Activity has not switchFragment method

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
protected void setContentFragment(Fragment contentFragment) {
    this.contentFragment = contentFragment;
    Random random = new Random(100);
    String rString = "myRandomString"+random.nextInt(); // Create a random string here everytime you call setContentFragment
    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment, rString).commit();
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

This will replace the fragment as you require

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

When swapping fragments you need to *detach/reattach instead of replacing them*. This leaves it in memory. Also you don't need to setContentView again, just leave the existing FrameLayout ( you could also use android.R.id.content for the main activity content view, instead of creating a FrameLayout)

```
Fragment content1, content2;
Fragment current=content1;

public void onCreate() {
  if(savedInstanceState==null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .add(android.R.id.content, content1)
      .commit();
}

public void swap() {
  if(current==content1) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .detach(content1)
      .attach(android.R.id.content, content2)
      .commit();
    current=content2;
  } else {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .detach(content2)
      .attach(android.R.id.content, content1)
      .commit();
    current=content1;
  }
```

}